# casts away qualifiers warning, how to avoid it?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile the following block of code

```
pthread_t threadDemo;
const char* msg = "Thread";
int ret = pthread_create(&threadDemo,NULL,worker_thread,(void*)msg);
pthread_join(threadDemo,NULL);
```

but the compiler returns the warning

```
warning: cast from type 'const char*' to type 'void*' casts away qualifiers [-Wcast-qual]
                     int ret = pthread_create(&threadDemo,NULL,worker_thread,(void*)msg);
```

How can I avoid the above warning?

thanks,

Comment: `const_cast<char*>(msg)` might work. Of course you must respect the constness of the data that `msg` is pointing to nevertheless.

Comment: `char msg[] = "Thread";` is another way to go

Comment: If you're writing C++ it's probably better to use `std::thread` instead of pthread to avoid dealing with these C-ism in the API